# Delaying API actions

Tags: c#, api, action, delay

I'm programming an API for my software, which has a lot of interfaces and my software just inherits them.
I want the API users to have the possibility to do something after X milliseconds, something like this :

```
public void PerformAction(Action action, int delay)
{
   Task.Run(async delegate
   {
       await Task.Delay(delai);
       Form.BeginInvoke(action);
       // I invoke on the Form because I think its better that the action executes in my main thread, which is the same as my form's thread
   });
}
```

Now i know that the Task is like a new Thread, I just want to know, is this bad for my software?  Is there any other possible better way?
The method will get executed a lot, so I don't know whether this approach is good or bad

Comment: Why don't you simply change your `PerformAction` to `async Task` and then just call `await Task.Delay(); action();` ? Starting a Task just to have it sleep then try to get back to the UI thread is *very* convoluted

Comment: Because i need the API users to use it like this : Client.PerformAction(TheirAction, 1000); because not every user will know the use of tasks / async

Comment: Actually they do, because the framework itself is full of asynchronous methods. You can't program .NET if you don't know about Tasks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not be creating a new Task for this, you can instead make the method a Task, something like this:

```
public async Task PerformAction(Action action, int delay)
{
   await Task.Delay(delay);
   action(); //this way you don't have to invoke the UI thread since you are already on it
}
```

And then simply use it like this:

```
public async void Butto1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await PerformAction(() => MessageBox.Show("Hello world"), 500);
}
```

Comment: What if they executed the method on a new thread they have created ?

Comment: @HaitamZanid in that case you will need to invoke the UI thread first. You could also explain how to use the API and let the users of the API read it when they face the Exception

Comment: So Form.BeginInvoke(action); is a bad idea ?

Comment: @HaitamZanid it's not a bad idea, just redundant if the API is used correctly. This is only required, of course, if the Action will interact with UI objects. If the Action will not use UI objects, then there's no need to invoke the UI thread

Comment: Its just that my software isn't for users who have a high level in c#, that's why i prefer to take care of some of the exceptions to make it easy ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
    public async Task PerformAction(Action action, int delay)
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay);
        action();
    }
```

Comment: `async void` is a very bad idea, because it can't be awaited and exceptions cna't be handled. It should only be used for event handlers (or similar methods with fire-and-forget semantics)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Mostly agreed, however, it is ok to use in UI event. cFrozenDeath has a better answer.

Comment: No, it's not OK. Your code may never fire, or `action()` may throw and go undetected.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You are correct. post updated. can you please cancel the down vote.